# How do you authorize ECS to create table in RDS using Python and Postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-rds, psycopg2, amazon-ecs

I'm using psycopg2 to create a db from an ECS instance to a RDS server.

This works on a local db but not for RDS:

```
def create_table(host_name,database_name,user_name,database_password): 
    #database_name is the target db - not the 'postgres' db we use for auth

    conn = connect(
        dbname = 'postgres',
        user = user_name,
        host = host_name,
        password = database_password
    ) 
    conn.set_isolation_level(extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + '"' + str(database_name) + '"')
```

Using the same user I can create a db from PGAdmin (`CREATE DATABASE test2;`) but not in ECS. The ECS error says: `psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege: permission denied to create database`. How is it possible that the same user is allowed to created a db from PGAdmin but not in ECS?

Comment: did you try creating the db from the python code on local?

Comment: Yes - it works locally

Comment: I don't think it is possible.  You are probably not really connecting as the same user, or the same system, in each case.